# Is it possible to let a user fill a google form in different sessions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I want a form where the user can fill some values and then exit, and then come back in some time and complete the form and submit it. Is it possible with google forms? If so, will the data entered in the second session be saved along with the corresponding row in the spreadsheet or will a new row be entered?I hope my question is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from the Form only goes to the server when it is submitted, so you cannot store that form data before submission (disregarding any data that might have gotten stored in the browser session).

What you could do instead is select **Settings** and check the option **Edit after submit**. This way, a user can submit the Form and then come back later to edit the responses.

#### Reference:

- [Google Forms: Allow people to edit responses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en&ref_topic=6063592)